# How to install distutils packages using distutils api or setuptools api

Tags: python, distutils, buildout

I'm working on a buildout script that needs to install a distutils package on remote server.

On PyPi there are 2 recipes for doing this
[collective.recipe.distutils 0.1 and zerokspot.recipe.distutils 0.1.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=recipe.distutils&submit=search).

The later module a derivative of the former, and is a little more convenient then the first, but the both suffer from the same problem, which I will describe now.

When bootstrap.py is executed, it downloads zc.buildout package and puts it into buildout's eggs directory. This gives ./bin/buildout access to zc.buildout code, but /usr/local/python does not know anything about zc.buildout at this point.

Buildout attepts to install the package by running 'python setup.py install' inside of a subprocess. This produces an ImportError because zc.buildout is not installed for /usr/local/python.

So, I have several solutions.

1. Install zc.buildout using easy_install on the remote server. I don't like this option at all, it makes a special case for a module that is very insignificant.
2. Modify zerokspot.recipe.distutils to put try block around 'import zc.buildout' this way, it will install even if zc.buildout is not installed. It's an ok solution, but somewhat hackish.
3. Replace subprocess with code that will install the package using distutils api or setuptools api. This would be the best solution in my opinion.

The question is how would i do #3?

Thank you,
Taras

PS: I solved the problem by creating another package that does not have dependancy on zc.buildout. My package is called [taras.recipe.distutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/taras.recipe.distutils) and it's available on pypi.

Comment: His question is 
"""
3. Replace subprocess with code that will install the package using distutils api or setuptools api. This would be the best solution in my opinion.

The question is how would i do #3?
"""

Answer (score 1):

You can call a command line program within your Python program using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python setup.py install')
```

However, how much control do you have over the environment that this install will be run? If it is a package that you are distributing, you will likely have issues no matter what solution people propose.  How will you handle cases of needing root access (e.g. sudo python setup.py install)?

You may consider looking into [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/) since it provides an API that is in some ways an extension of setuptools.

Comment: Oh I was doing my usual turkey lurky action, but I checked out Paver.  Might be the solution for me... thanks

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I was trying to avoid. I updated the post with better information.

Answer (score 1):

zerokspot.recipe.distutils is fundamentally broken in that it adds a dependency on zc.buildout in it's setup.py, as follows:

1. `setup.py` imports `get_version` from `zerokspot.recipe.distutils`
2. All of `zerokspot.recipe.distutils` is defined in it's `__init__.py`, including `get_version`
3. `__init__.py` in `zerokspot.recipe.distutils` imports `zc.buildout`

Why the author defines `get_version` is a mystery to me; best practice keeps a simple version string in `setup.py` itself and lets setuptools deal with dev versions (through `setup.cfg`), and distutils for version metadata extraction.

Generally it is not a good idea to import the whole package in `setup.py` as that would require all the package dependencies to be present at install time. Obviously the author of the package has zc.buildout installed as a site-wide package and didn't notice his oversight.

Your best bet is to fork the package on github, remove the get_version dependency, and propose the change to the original author while you use your fork instead.

Comment: Hey Martijn,
I agree with you on all of the point.
But I'd still like to find out how to do #3.
Thanks,
Taras

Comment: I followed your suggestion. But I did not work with zerokspot's developer because I did not want to wait.

I'd still like to learn how to do #3.

Comment: Sorry for the late response (tons of stress and tons of spam in my inbox that hid the message by tarasm). Regarding the dependency on the whole package from within the setup.py: Sorry for that, I fixed that in a few other packages but it seems like I missed it in a few. Will update that package ASAP.

Btw.: If you find an issue with my code like "... is fundamentally broken", there is something nice on github called an issue-tracker ;-)

Comment: Heh, the OP could indeed have used the issue-tracker for that. :-) Sorry for sounding dismissive of your package, I didn't look too deeply into it's qualities, only to solve the question at hand.

Comment: @Horst Gutmann, thank you for maintaining this package. I forked your package which was wrong thing to do. I'm going to close my package, start using yours again and if anything else comes up, I'll make a patch and submit it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to just generate a [bdist](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because I'm packaging the code on one platform and installing it on another. I want to modify an existing buildout recipe  so I just need this code.